# How to monitor events on an Solidity Smart Contract using hardhat and ethers?

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js, ethers.js, hardhat

I'd like to monitor events happening on-chain on a specific Smart Contract. I'd like to know every time a `Transfer` event happens. I tried to write a code with hardhat, but no events if being logged. Here is my code:

```js
  const abi = [
    "event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 indexed id)"
  ]

  const MyContract = await new hre.ethers.Contract(
    "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48",
    abi,
    hre.ethers.provider
  )

  MyContract.on("Transfer", (from, to, id) => {
    console.log("Transfered:", from, to, id)
  })
  console.log("monitoring...")
```

I know that there are events occurring in the blockchain, but my code is not tracking them. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please share the contract as well

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a web socket provider:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider("wss://...");
```

Second, there is some issue with the way you provide the abi... If you are using hardhat, I would highly recommend "hardhat-abi-exporter" package. You can then specify which abis you want to generate for further use in scripts. If you don't want to do this - providing such fragment will do the job:

```
const abi = [
    {
      anonymous: false,
      inputs: [
        {
          indexed: true,
          internalType: "address",
          name: "from",
          type: "address",
        },
        {
          indexed: true,
          internalType: "address",
          name: "to",
          type: "address",
        },
        {
          indexed: false,
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "value",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      name: "Transfer",
      type: "event",
    },
  ];
```